# Express, AJAX - res.send not sending any data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am building an app with a Node/Express/Mongo backend and using simple jquery on the frontend.

When I make an Ajax POST to my server, res.send does not seem to send any data able to be caught by the POST success function.

This is is my frontend AJAX code -

```
$(".signup-form").submit(function(e){

    var createUrl = $('.tutor-checkbox').is(':checked') ? serverUrls.createTutor : serverUrls.createStudent;
    var formInput = {
        email: $('#signup-email-input').val(),
        password: $('#signup-password-input').val(),
        first_name: $('#firstname-input').val(),
        last_name: $('#lastname-input').val()
    };

    formInput = JSON.stringify({
        user: formInput
    });

    $.ajax({
      url:createUrl,
      type:"POST",
      data: formInput,
      contentType:"application/json",
      dataType:"JSON",
      success: function(data){
        console.log("success: ", data);
        window.location = data.redirect;
      }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

The printout in the Browser console is:

```
success:  undefined main.js:45
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of undefined main.js:46
```

My server route code is:

```
app.post('/api/createtutor', function(req, res){

db.createUser(Tutor.model, req.body.user)
.then(function(data){

    var queryString = utils.serialize({
        first_name: req.body.user.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.user.last_name
    });

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    res.status(304).send({
        redirect: "/tutor-profile-form?" + queryString
    });

})
.catch(function(err){
    res.status(404).end(JSON.stringify(err));
})
```

});

Can someone please let me know what is wrong? I have been stuck on this for ages!

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: does data contain any redirect function or object?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava, no the data is just JSON object with the uri to be redirected. the redirection will be handled on client-side.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava, i expect the AJAX success function to receive 
data in form of:
`code` { redirect: "/tutor-profile-form?first_name=test&last_name=test" }

Answer (score 0):

```
e.preventDefault();
```

should be the first line. So:

```
$(".signup-form").submit(function(e){
    // This should be line one
    e.preventDefault();

    var createUrl = $('.tutor-checkbox').is(':checked') ? serverUrls.createTutor : serverUrls.createStudent;
   // etc etc
})
```

Comment: I have changed to first line and it still does not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:

The problem was the promise I had in the server:

```
db.createUser(Tutor.model, req.body.user)
.then(function(data){

...
```

I used Q library to promisify the function and for some reason Express did not like it and did not execute the res.send.

I changed it back to a normal callback and it worked.